# Has it been proved that ∨ ∧ ¬ ⇒ ⇔ ∀ ∃ and predicates are enough to express all known mathematics?

Tags: logic, foundations

I frequently encounter this statement in math books:
"All of known mathematics can be expressed in terms of elementary predicates, logical connectives, and quantifiers."

Comment: A proof would consist in flipping through all pages of all *known* math books and verifying that these are enough ...

Comment: See if these are enough to formulate the language of set theory.

Comment: It might be interesting to note that $\implies$ and $\iff$ can be expressed in terms of the first three.

Comment: @Streamyroot i know, and ⟹ can be expressed using ∨ and ¬ so, basically there are 5 symbols

Comment: This statement is not amenable to mathematical proof. Can you give references to the books where you "frequently encounter" it?

Comment: Is that statement even true?  What about basic relations?  How would you express concepts involving $\in$ ?  On a side note, the $K$, $S$ and $U$ combinator are enough to express all of the operators in the title, with $U$ defined to express $UAB \approx \lnot \exists x ~ A(x) \land B(x)$

Comment: @RobArthan "a book of set theory" by Charles c Pinter: "All of known mathematics can be expressed in terms of elementary predicates, logical connectives, and quantifiers." and "how to prove it" by Daniel J Velleman: "We have now introduced seven basic logical symbols: the connectives ∧, ∨, ¬, →, and ↔, and the quantifiers ∀ and ∃. It is a remarkable fact that the structure of all mathematical statements can be understood using these symbols, and all mathematical reasoning can be analyzed in terms of the proper use of these symbols."

Comment: @JohnJack: OK. "At least twice" is a good start towards "frequently".

Comment: @RobArthan those are the only books im reading right now and both of them mentioned this fact.

Comment: "Proved", no; "demonstrated", yes. The statement isn't provable in the mathematical sense of proof. But more than a century of experience with the language of set theory (in one guise or another) makes the case that first order logic, with one or more predicates and the right axioms, suffices to express current mathematics.

Answer (score 1):

You need a concept of *proof* that is

- sound in the sense that anything that's provable from a given set of hypotheses is true in every model in which the hypotheses are true, and
- effective, in the sense that there is a proof-checking algorithm.

It would also be nice for it to be

- complete in the sense that every proposision true in every model in which the hypotheses are true can be proved from those hypotheses.

That the logic based on the symbols you list satisfies the three bullet points was proved in the 1930s, provided you allow Gödel's non-constructive proof of the third point.

The second point raises the question: What is an algorithm.  The answer is that it is that which can be done by your favorite general-purpose progamming language.  For any two such languages, any algorithm in one of them can be written in the other: this has been checked carefully and extensively.

Could there be something that we would recognize as an algorithm that cannot be expressed in those languages?  That is a maddening question.  I don't think anyone knows how to make it precise.  But if such a thing were found, it would not be currently known math.  The proposition that there can be no such thing is the [Church–Turing thesis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Church%E2%80%93Turing_thesis).

The theory of sets is expressed using the symbols you list, and sometimes it is asserted that all known mathematics can be encoded within that (and sometimes it is asserted that not all of it can).

Comment: The question is about expressivity of a language and not about proof.

Comment: @RobArthan : At least it superficially appears that way, but I'm not so sure. $\qquad$